# Android testing with Robolectric and AndroidAnnotations

Tags: android, robolectric, android-annotations

I've developing application using AndroidAnnotations and want to use Robolectric for unit testing.

I can't get it working though.
Application and tests are placed in single project.
Source is placed under `/src/main/java` and test under `/src/test/java`. Both folders are source folders.

When running test from Eclipse using Eclipse JUnit launcher I get:

```
Class not found org.demoapp.MyActivityTest
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.demoapp.MyActivityTest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:693)
```

When running from commandline `mvn clean test` I get:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project demo-app: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] \demo-app\src\test\java\org\demoapp\MyActivityTest.java:[3,16] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] \demo-app\src\test\java\org\demoapp\MyActivityTest.java:[4,23] package org.junit.runner does not exist
[ERROR] \demo-app\src\test\java\org\demoapp\MyActivityTest.java:[6,33] package com.xtremelabs.robolectric does not exist
[ERROR] \demo-app\src\test\java\org\demoapp\MyActivityTest.java:[8,1] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class RunWith
...
...
```

Although all classes compiles in eclipse.

Actually I don't know what's the problem here. Where should I start?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.demoapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>Demo :: App</name>

    <properties>
        <environment>development</environment>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.libphonenumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>libphonenumber</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.androidannotations</groupId>
            <artifactId>androidannotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.androidannotations</groupId>
            <artifactId>androidannotations</artifactId>
            <classifier>api</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pivotallabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <manifest>
                        <debuggable>true</debuggable>
                    </manifest>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>manifestUpdate</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>manifest-update</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>alignApk</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>zipalign</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[3.2.0,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>manifest-update</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>development</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>environment</name>
                    <value>!production</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <deployment.stage>In Development</deployment.stage>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <properties>
                <deployment.stage>In Production</deployment.stage>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>release</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>performRelease</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>signing</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>sign</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <inherited>true</inherited>
                                <configuration>
                                    <removeExistingSignatures>true</removeExistingSignatures>
                                    <archiveDirectory />
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}.apk</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <keystore>keystore/keys.keystore</keystore>
                                    <alias>alias</alias>
                                    <storepass>${sign.storepass}</storepass>
                                    <keypass>${sign.keypass}</keypass>
                                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                        <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.3.0</version>
                        <inherited>true</inherited>
                        <configuration>
                            <sign>
                                <debug>false</debug>
                            </sign>
                            <zipalign>
                                <verbose>true</verbose>
                                <inputApk>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}.apk</inputApk>
                                <outputApk>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-signed-aligned.apk
                                </outputApk>
                            </zipalign>
                            <manifest>
                                <debuggable>false</debuggable>
                                <versionName>${project.version}</versionName>
                                <versionCodeAutoIncrement>true</versionCodeAutoIncrement>
                            </manifest>
                            <proguard>
                                <skip>true</skip>
                            </proguard>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>manifestUpdate</id>
                                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>manifest-update</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>alignApk</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>zipalign</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
                <artifactId>android</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.libphonenumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>libphonenumber</artifactId>
                <version>5.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.androidannotations</groupId>
                <artifactId>androidannotations</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.androidannotations</groupId>
                <artifactId>androidannotations</artifactId>
                <classifier>api</classifier>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: Please attach your project's pom.xml.

Comment: The first failure is a known bug (see my comments below), however, you should able to run it via command line, according to the error log in you second failure, it looks like something worng with your project's classpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your pom.xml, you set the source directory to `src`, but you say that your sources are in `src/main/java` folder and you tests in `src/test/java`.

Could you try to remove the `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>`, so Maven use this default file structure ?

Also, for now, I have never been able to launch unit test with robolectric from Eclipse... But it works with maven.

Comment: This is an [known bug](https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/52) of m2e-android (or perhaps m2e). I guess the root cause is Eclipse JUnit Runner prefer a different output directory from what Android ADT used as default, see my comments in [releated bug](https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/15). I am able to make Eclipse JUnit Test singing by manually copy contents under bin/ to target/classes, As you can see, this is quite dirty as your need do this everytime code is modified.

Comment: OK moving forward :) Should my pom include anything else? As now I get 'java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint not present' error.

Comment: Did you add the following dependency ?  <dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.android.maps</groupId>
  <artifactId>maps</artifactId>
  <version>10_r2</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>

Comment: I need it even though I don't use it? That's odd. It works with that dependency.